# "More precisely" usage

Tags: expression-choice

After describing a certain issue in a more general manner I want to outline the inner details of it. Is it correct to start the paragraph whose purpose it is to give to the reader the detailed explanation with the following expression?

> More precisely,...

Or are there other expressions which would fit better given the above scope?

Comment: If you start the previous paragraph with "_Generally,_", then "_More precisely,_" is a parallel introductory transition. If you don't, there are many other possibilities, e.g., "_To be more specific,". This is a style and not a usage question. Expression choices are usually style choices. As with most style choices, context dictates what should or does or doesn't work. No specific context (as with this question) means no specific answer.

Comment: It's fine to say *More precisely,...* so long as you are following the same structure as earlier with more detail. However, note that this expression better suits for short explanations than seems to be the context -- a longer discussion following a short general intro.

Comment: Why the close/ down votes?

Comment: @Kris "Is this grammatically correct" questions are generally closed "too basic"; and, even if they weren't, it is impossible to give a factual answer in this case where all we have is a sentence fragment.

Comment: I suppose we *need* to say that much, every time, when voting to close; how's the new member to know (ok, there's FAQ)? Silent voting is bad practice :).

Comment: On second thoughts, we could migrate this to writersSE.

Answer (score 2):

You could use "To be more precise".